# Using aggregate with a complex FUN argument

Tags: r, aggregate, geometry

I am interested in calculating hourly averages. In the past I have had success using the aggregate function like so:

```
Time<-c("1:00","1:20","1:40","2:00","2:20","2:40","3:00","3:20","3:40","4:00","4:20","4:40")
Hour<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
Bearing<-c(10,20,30,350,3,20,170,195,200,300,20,50)

DF<-data.frame(Time,Hour,Bearing)

ByHR<-aggregate(.~Hour,data=DF,mean)
```

In this way, I get an hourly average of my Bearing data. But now I want to use the circ.mean() function to calculate means of circular data.

```
library(CircStats)
deg(circ.mean(rad(DF$Bearing)))
```

And I can't just plug in the above function in the above aggregate code as I get an error. So is there a way to use a more complex FUN argument with aggregate? If not, what would be the best way to apply the circ.mean() function by hour in the above data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try writing your own function as a wrapper for the complex function?

```
my_fun <- function(x) deg(circ.mean(rad(x)))
aggregate(.~Hour, data=DF, my_fun)
```

There's also the anonymous function approach:

```
aggregate(.~Hour, data=DF, function(x) deg(circ.mean(rad(x))) )
```